# Can I connect 2 or more RTCPeerConnection using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

Can I connect more than 1 RTCpeerconnection using socket.io?
Client:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection()
socket.emit("peer",pc)
socket.on("peerAnswer",(peer)=>{
    pc.addIceCandidate(peer)
})
```

Server:

```
io.on("connection",(socket)=>{
    socket.on("peer",(peer)=>{socket.broadcast.emit("peerAnswer",peer)})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed create multiple peerconnections using socket.io. To achieve this you would need to send the offer/answer to specific sockets.

Here is a [full example](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer) of multi user video chat using [simple-peer](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer). Which is basically a wrapper for RTCPeerConnection. In `/public/js/main.js` you can see that there is a command through socket to create a new peerconnection object. These are all stored in a list.

On server-side `/src/socketController.js` all socket connection are also stored in a list to be referenced later.

[Github project](https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer)

[DEMO](https://dirvann-webrtc-video.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: I see a screen share code block in the code but seems like it is not working or you disable it intentionally?